# Rerender component not working when attribute value is changing

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender

**TestComponent.component**:

```
<apex:component >

<apex:attribute name="test_attribute" type="String" description="Test Attribute"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" rendered="{!IF(test_attribute='first',TRUE,FALSE)}">
    <p>From first panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel> 

<apex:outputPanel id="thatpanel" rendered="{!IF(test_attribute='second',TRUE,FALSE)}">
    <p>From second panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**Visualforce page:**:

```
    <apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jquery_1_11_3}"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction(variable){
            if(variable == "first"){
                $("[id$='componentId']").attr("test_attribute","first");

            }else if(variable == "second"){
                $("[id$='componentId']").attr("test_attribute","second");
            }
            console.log('component attribute is now set to '+ $("[id$='componentId']").attr("test_attribute"));
            refreshPanel();
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="refreshPanel" rerender="componentPanel"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="testFunction('first')">Click for First component panel</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onclick="testFunction('second')">Click for Second component panel</a>
        <br/>
        <apex:outputPanel id="componentPanel">
            <c:TestComponent id="componentId" test_attribute="first"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

[image]

I have two links on Visualforce page. Clicking on each link will invoke a javascript function which will set the component attribute to a different value and calls the action function which rerenders the outputPanel which contains the component.

I posted the complete code including screenshot and console log showing that component attribute is changing but it is not rerendering.

Any help on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code finally worked..Looks like we cannot modify the attribute value of the component via javascript and expect it to rerender. Spent almost half day to learn this :)

Hopefully this helps somebody in the future..

```
<apex:page controller="CustomController">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:actionFunction name="refreshPanel" rerender="componentPanel">
            <apex:param name="myParam" value="" assignTo="{!test_String}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <a href="#" onclick="refreshPanel('first'); return false;">Click for First component panel</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onclick="refreshPanel('second'); return false;">Click for Second component panel</a>
        <br/>

        <apex:outputPanel id="componentPanel">
            <c:TestComponent id="componentId" test_attribute="{!test_String}"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```